# Unable to move files and folders

Tags: 12.04, filesystem, file-sharing, filemanager

I use Ubuntu 12.04 and all my drives are of the ext4 file system. I tried to cut and paste a folder from the location /home/username/Documents to a logical drive which is of the ext4 file system but I couldn't. There was no option for paste at all. I tried ctrl+v but that also didn't work. Why is that and what do I need to do to move the folder?

Comment: Do you have write rights to the folder you would like to paste to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by formatting my partitions to NTFS file system which were of ext4 file system previously.

Answer (score 0):

most probably user rights problem.
try to start nautilus/filemanager with sudo from terminal and check if you are able to do it as a root. If yes, it is enough to set up correct user rights on destination drive.